# I need to condense this javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the javascript code below to work with any of the following links:

```
<a href="#" class="example1">http://example.com</a>
<a href="#" class="test">Doesnt work now</a>
```

The code that is displayed after the link is clicked:

```
<div style='display:none'>
   <div id='example1' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
      <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code I need condensed to work with any class/id values I give:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".example1").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#example1"});
        $(".example2").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#example2"});
        $(".example3").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#example3"});
        $(".example4").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#example4"});
        $(".example5").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#example5"});
    });
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried to write? This looks like a please-do-my-homework-for-me question.

Comment: Are you using a plug-in that allows `.colorbox` to be used or is there another function not shown?

Comment: This is working as it is on a current website. I just need to be able to put any value in the link class and match it up to the div id. `.colorbox` is a plug-in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("[class^='example']").each(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({width:"50%", 
                      inline:true, 
                      href:"#example" + $(this).attr("class").replace("example", "")
    });
});
```

or even simpler:

```
$("[class^='example']").each(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({width:"50%", 
                      inline:true, 
                      href:"#" + $(this).attr("class")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myColorBox(myClass, myLink) {
  return $("."+myClass).colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:myLink});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are asking but it sounds like you need a general method to perform the actions listed in your JavaScript snippet.  Try something like this:

```
function doColorBox(sel, href) {
  return $(sel).colorbox({width:'50%', inline:true, href:href});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  doColorBox('.example1', '#example1');
  doColorBox('.test', 'http://test.com');
  doColorBox('#foo', '#foo');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for, I believe, [http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/LggeY/](http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/LggeY/1/). It gets the `a` tag's class and then shows a `div` with the corresponding ID.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop might actually be more condensed than some of these clever uses of bits of the jQuery API.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    $(".example" + i).colorbox({width:"50%", inline: true, href:"#example" + i});
});
```